# Putting a 'colon' after table caption instead of a 'dot', in deluxetable environment

Tags: tables, captions, deluxetable

I am trying to make a table with the deluxetable environment. I provided the deluxetable.sty file in the same folder as my .tex file. A minimal working example looks like the following:

```
%\onecolumngrid
\begin{deluxetable}{||c c c||}
\tablecaption{Mass fraction yields of isotopes .\label{simtable} \vspace*{15pt} }
\vspace{10pt}
\bigskip
%\tablehead{\colhead {Isotopes} & \colhead {Ejecta} & \colhead {Fallback } \vspace*{20pt}  }
\tablehead{\colhead {Isotopes} & \colhead {Ejecta} & \colhead {Fallback } }
\startdata
${}^{16}$O & $3.71 \times 10^{-1}$  & $6.43 \times 10^{-1}$  \\ 
${}^{28}$Si & $2.60 \times 10^{-1}$  & $5.40 \times 10^{-2}$  \\
\enddata

\end{deluxetable}
```

The only problem is that my table caption has a 'dot' after it instead of a 'colon'. I am wondering if there is any way I can put the colon after caption. I have the following in my .tex file already. But it does not seem to make any difference to table caption:

```
\usepackage{deluxetable}
\usepackage{caption} \captionsetup{labelfont=normalfont,labelsep=colon}
```

Comment: Your snippet is not a minimal working example. A minimal example can be compiled. That means it should start with \documentclass and end with \end{document}.

Comment: For starters, please tell us which document class you employ.